# Constructing a NFA from a right linear grammar, is this correct?

Tags: automata

Given the right linear grammar G

```
S -> abA | bbB  | a
A -> bB  | aA   | b
B -> baB | aaaA | [Epsilon/Terminates]
```

Is the NFA in the image below the proper construction of an NFA M(G) from the grammar?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks very good, and I think you certainly have the right idea.  I see one minor mistake:  I think the labels are switched on the two bottommost arrows labeled `a` and `b`.  If I understand correctly, that accepting node represents strings that can be generated from $B$, and the two arrows below it represent the $B\to\mathtt{ba}B$ production, so the `b` arrow should come first on a path around the loop.

If I were doing this, I would label the $B$ node (the rightmost of the three accepting states) and the $A$ node (the node in the row second from right, with the loop) so that the grader will have an easy time seeing that your answer is correct.